# Filter DateTime from 2 timestamps

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, filter

I have a DateTime column in a MySQL table that I'm trying to filter just from the time of the DateTime. So for example I need all rows that the time is 8am-9am on any date. Is this possible? I've looked through all the docs and can't find anything of the sort.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TIME` function, like this

```
where TIME(myColumn) >= '08:00:00' and TIME(myColumn) <= '09:00:00'
```

`TIME` gets the time part of your value.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I would + rep but I don't have sufficient rep to do so.